# How to make a popover visible on a scrollable list?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a problem with a popover in bootstrap 3. I have a list in `<ul>` tag where I show the notifications as in the photo.

[image]

But to make the `<ul>` scrollable I applied some css on it like below:

```
.scrollable-menu {
max-height: 25em;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Scrolling is working perfecly but the `overflow-x` attribute is hiding the popover content as well. Tried to override the `overflow-x` on the popover but did not work. I tried `z-index` as well but no success...

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `overflow-x: visible;` for  `.scrollable-menu` ?

Comment: It solve the popover issue but the menu is not scrollable anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `placement` to the right or set `overflow-x: visible` for `.scrollable-menu`.

in html:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Content">Hover</a>
```

js:

```
$('.popover').popover({
    trigger:'hover',
    placement: 'right'
});
```

**UPDATE**:

you can append the popover to `body` like this:

```
$('.popover').popover({
    container : 'body'
});
```

and set `z-index` to high level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but setting the `overflow-x: visible` will make the list non-scrollable, while setting the popover to right its not a good option since the popover itself is a directive in angularjs used in many places in the application, and it will change in all the places...

Answer (score 0):

I updated the directive like @Damon.s  advised me and worked perfectly.

```
$(el).popover({
      trigger: 'hover',
      html: true,
      container: 'body',
      content: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
      placement: 'bottom'
 });
```